# How To Confirm Angular App Proxy is Working Properly (v7)

Tags: angular, proxy, command-line-interface

My Angluar app api is on a different port (`:8087`) than the application runs on (`:4200`) in `ng serve`.

I am trying to get the requests for api, like: `/api/settings` to go to `http://localhost:8087/api/settings` instead of `http://localhost:4200/api/settings`.

I've tried setting up a proxy following along with something like this: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server but something isn't working, and I don't really understand it enough to know what I should expect.

I get the expected response when I contact the API directly through `http://localhost:8087/api/settings`.

I run the application just with: `ng serve`.

*proxy.conf.json:*

```
    {
      "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8087",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
      }
    }
```

```
    [HPM] GET /api/store/categories -> http://localhost:8087
    [HPM] GET /api/store/cart -> http://localhost:8087
    [HPM] GET /api/settings -> http://localhost:8087
```

The network request in the browser shows as `Request URL: http://localhost:4200/api/settings`... but i'm not sure if this should reflect the different port. Should it?

Angular CLI: 7.0.6 |
Node: 8.11.1 |
OS: win32 x64 |
Angular: 7.0.4

What actually happens is I get thrown into this never ending loop of one going back to the other (which could be some problem with the routing, but I need to confirm if the proxy is working as it should be first).

Comment: Try removing `"changeOrigin": true,` and change `/api/*` to simply `/api`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky have tried both of those things to no avail. Do you kow how I can confirm it's working? Like, is that message in the logger what you would expect? I would expect to see: 
`[HPM] GET /api/settings -> http://localhost:8087/api/settings`

Comment: Can you please confirm the npm command you are using to run your Angular application, given the proxy? Also, if you execute an API call in something like the base App component, do you get a response or any errors? Also, can you confirm that if you hit the API endpoint directly, do you get the appropriate response (either throw browser or a tool such as Postman or cURL)? Please update your question to reflect that information. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I updated my original question to answer your questions. :)

Comment: Can you please try running Angular with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` and let me know if makes a difference. Or do you have the proxy registered in `angular.json`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Runing the application w/the `--proxy-config` flag doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Okay, disregarding the logger temporarily, in the running application, are the responses coming through? I assume you are making HTTP calls using ` HttpClient` in components or services? Inspecting the browser's developer tools network tab, are you seeing responses coming through as you expect?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky No, the network tab shows the responses coming from :4200 (failing)

Comment: Last question, can you please share the error message from the console/network tab(s)? Also, you have the `proxyConfig` property set in your `angular.json`?

Comment: I can confirm that the browser will show the Request URL as `http://localhost:4200/api/settings` and the proxy logger will show it as `[HPM] GET /api/settings -> http://localhost:8087`. I was able to use this configuration with a simple express server using command `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` with both client and server running with HttpClient get(). You'd need to confirm the error you are getting as it could be a number of issues ranging from CORS to something happening on the server causing the response to fail. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky ahh, thanks! So the proxy is doing what it's supposed to do, and the problem must lie with the fact that we are using IIS virtual directories. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your configuration to the following:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8087",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

You don't need `changeOrigin` because your API in this development setting is also on `localhost`. If you were calling some kind of external API, it may be necessary, but not when both the server and client are on `localhost`.

To answer your question regarding how to determine if it's working. Execute API calls to these respective endpoints from your components/services/etc and see if you get the data you expect. The logger, even with level "debug" set, will not show this information. The browser developer tools network tab will not show calls being made to `http://localhost:8087/`, it will show `http://localhost:4200/`. If you can receive data from the endpoint, that means it working.

If you want to enhance the log output to show full paths, you could consider using the [http-proxy-middleware events](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/README.md#http-proxy-events) such as `onProxyReq()` and `onProxyRes()`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yeah, I have tried both. I saw some articles that said one and some the other. I just need to be able to verify it is doing what I've asked it to (via dev tools or the logger).

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to figure out why my proxy is not logging any debug output. Then I found the following article on Medium:

- https://medium.com/@gagandeep.sidhu88/how-to-fix-logging-for-proxy-in-angular-834cf46d437d

It answers my question in full. But since having link-only answers is discouraged on Stack Overflow, I will also include main parts from it. Instead of `proxy.conf.json` you will have `proxy.conf.js` with code similar to this:

```
var winston = require('winston'); //(1)

function logProvider() { //(2)
  return winston.createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.splat(),
      winston.format.simple()
    ),
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  });
}

var PROXY_CONF = {
  '/local': {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    logProvider: logProvider, // (3)
    cookiePathRewrite: '/local/',
    pathRewrite: {
      '/local': '/carm-services-web/services',
    },
  },
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONF;
```

[winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) is a logging library and needs to be installed via:

```
npm i -D winston
```

Then after npm run start is done its initial build, and you load your app, you will start seeing debug entries in the following format:

```
debug: [HPM] POST /YOUR_API/ -> http://localhost
```

Any API request which was not proxied will show up in this list, so you will know if more proxy entries need to be configured.